# How to Handle These Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm having a situation where i have 10 resources(controllers) that correspond to 10 database entries. In particular, it is about buildings. There is a town_center controller, a sawmill controller and more.

I did not want to create a buildings_controller and handle everything there, since each building behaves very differently.

But i have a question on routes and how to handle a particular situation. I would ideally want to have urls like :

```
/town_center/view
/sawmill/view
```

This is fine, but i have a fundamental problem. There is no easy way to get the town_center id number from the url. I would of course need this information, in order to get model information about the particular building. Now, one could argue that i can just use this :

```
/town_center/view/1
/sawmill/view/2
```

Which seems fine, but poses another fundamental problem, and that is, that i have to specify the id, when i redirect from another controller. Say that i want to redirect to the town_center controller. I would need to do :

```
redirect_to town_center_url(1)
```

Which i really don't like, because the id can change anytime in my database and is generally a bad programming practice for sure, very prone to errors.

How would you handle this ? Am i missing a simpler way ?

EDIT :

EXAMPLE ROUTES WITH ID NEEDED

```
  scope :path => '/town_center', :controller => :town_center do
    get '/view/:id' => :view, :as => 'town_center'
  end

  scope :path => '/sawmill', :controller => :sawmill do
    get '/view/:id' => :view, :as => 'sawmill'
  end
```

EXAMPLE OF USAGE

Starting from /overview, we see a list of building links like :

```
/town_center/view/1
/sawmill/view/2
```

If one clicks on the first, the view action with an :id of 1 is executed. Fine till now. But say that on this view template, there is an action like send_message. Now, this action is like :

```
def send_message
   send_the_message_blah_blah
   redirect_to sawmill_url(2)
end
```

Now, i guess the problem is clear. In order to redirect to the sawmill viewpath, i need to know its id, which means that i would have to make an extra query, for no real reason, like :

```
def send_message
   send_the_message_blah_blah
   redirect_to sawmill_url(Building.where(:name=>'sawmill').first)
end
```

And if i don't include the :id in the url at all, then my view action is just not aware of what building it should refer to.

Comment: I'm confused, can you post your `routes.rb`?

Comment: edited to illustrate my current routes

Comment: did you know you can use the instance variables in your paths/urls? Unless I am mistaken, wouldn't this make it easy for you? redirect_to town_center_url @some_town_center

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a little more albeit I'm getting kinda drowsy. In your `Sawmill Controller` you have an action called `view` right? Could you post it too?

Comment: @yakiimo yes, i know that, but it still comes down to the same problem, that i have to get the town_center information, while there is just one town center having an id of 1(or whatever the database creates as auto_increment). It seems like extra code for no real reason :/

Comment: I don't understand how the behaviour of each building type is causing you to create specialized resources. Are you adding custom actions to the controller? What are you doing that can't be done while following the Rails golden path?

Comment: @SrdjanPejic Yes, exactly, there are lots of custom actions for each building. For example, an army building would need to have an action named recruit. All those led me to create a different controller for each. Do you think that i should go back to having just a buildings resource ? Wouldn't that create a very hefty buildings controller ? It really seems to me that separate controllers is a better approach,but i could be wrong.

Comment: I agree with SpyrosP on breaking this up into multiple controllers.
But I don't see why putting the id in the URL is a problem? 99.9% of web applications work that way and the rails helpers make it very easy not to worry about this kind of stuff.

Maybe you could point out what problems you are having exactly with putting the ID in there?

Also why didn't you use the resources :army_buildings way inside your routes but rather the rails2 syntax?

Comment: @Tigraine It's still rails 3 syntax, it's just that i like to write my routes manually, it does not affect the problem by any means, don't worry about it. The id in the url is a problem when i need to redirect to a url via another controller, where i don't have the building information and i have to execute a query just to get that(i'm analyzing that in my question with redirect_to town_center_url(1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if it were me, I would change my `routes` up and put a `before_filter` in each controller that does the query for you.

So like each one of your `routes` would look something like this instead.

```
scope :path => '/sawmill', :controller => :sawmill do
  get '/view' => :view, :as => 'sawmill'
end
```

then in your `SawmillController` you would add the before filter to get the `sawmill` from the database.

```
class SawmillController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_sawmill
  ...
private
  def get_sawmill
    @sawmill = Building.where(:name=>'sawmill').first
  end
end
```

That way anytime someone takes action on a controller, they won't even know that there is a database behind it. The controller does all the legwork **AFTER** the request is made.

This way you cut the `:id` out of your url and `_url` methods completely. Meaning just `sawmill_url` instead of `sawmill_url(1)`, and your url will be `/sawmill/view`. Nice and clean!

Comment: this is what i would want to avoid really. I thought of things like that and this is why i originally asked this question. It seems that maybe i will just have to stick to specifically executing a query each time i want to redirect this way.

Comment: Huh? This way the query isn't performed until after you've viewed the page. If you're looking at `database` information anyway then this will just load the data at the same time. The url method would be `sawmill_url` and the actual url would be `/sawmill/view` without the `:id`

Comment: ohhh sorry, i misunderstood, my bad. So you are just getting an instance variable, being the first db entry. That is very interesting and can indeed be a nice solution. Give me some time to test it and see how it works in my app. +1 anyway, nice idea.

Comment: After rereading your questions and my answer, I could see why you misunderstood. I'll edit it and make it clearer.

Comment: I tested it and like it, works like a charm and i do not need to specify the id whatsoever. Very neat, thanx !

Comment: btw, in case people are having a similar problem, i make it a bit smaller using a lambda as well, like "before_filter lambda{ @town_center = Building.where(:slug => 'town_center').first }"

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/town_center/view/:id' => 'town_center#view'
```

if you have a view action in your controller, but why are you fighting the convention. just have:

```
resources :town_center
```

you would call town_center(instance_of_a_town_center) which would give you the path

/town_center/1

why do you need the view? its just the get method for an instance of a town_center in the town_center controller.

hope this helps

Comment: that's actually mentioned in the above comments to my question. It would be quite tedious to use the instance, because i would need to get it, thus executing a useless query. I don't particulary need the view, but i thought that since there is a single town center only, town_center/view would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This makes me think either you don't understand the way rails wants you to do things or that your situation has some special considerations that we are still not aware of:

*(edit: looking at your answer history, it seems you know much more about rails than I do so I'm guessing it's the second. please skip to the bottom of this question for my request for you)*

> redirect_to town_center_url(1)
>   Which i really don't like, because the id can change anytime in my
>   database and is generally a bad programming practice for sure, very
>   prone to errors.

The only solution I know for accessing a resource without some kind of id is through some other contextual information. For example with the devise authentication system, you don't ever use your id anywhere. If you are authenticated, then the server knows who you are and doesn't want to throw your id around unnecessarily in urls or whatever. So similarly if you have someone logged in, you can identify their resources through their session.

**example controller (should probably be in a town model actually):**

```
@tc = current_user.town_center
@b = current_user.barracks
```

**view**

```
<%= link_to 'Town Center', @tc %> <%# which still is using some identifier %>
```

Or if you had a "location" then you could identify the lone town_center through the location  similar to above (but now you need the location identifier).

Basically, unless you have some special context, you will need an identifier somewhere.

If that doesn't help, I think you should walk us through one example of how you would like for things to work from zero (user comes to your page. what do they see?) to .... somehow opening a building resource (when does the building originally become available?) to... doing some action with that building.

Comment: hi there, thanx for the reply. Yes, i actually knew about using an instance variable to do that, but it seems pretty reduntant for what i want. If you think about it from zero, think that there are many buildings, but each one is practically a different resource. Now, a town_center, for instance, refers to a single town_center entry in the Building model. Now, i would normally not use an id, because it's just not needed. However, when i try to access /town_center/view in my view action, i just can't find a nice way to get the town_center building information(i would not want a session var).